# p:wizard onnext not stopping 'navigation'

Tags: jsf, primefaces, wizard

When I'm using p:wizard, I use a custom handler for onnext attribute,the handler just alert and return false to test behavior.

As I understand from the wizard.js in primefaces library, that on clicking the next button of the wizard, the below code should execute:

```
next: function () {
        if (this.cfg.onnext) {
            var b = this.cfg.onnext.call(this);
            if (b == false) {
                return
            }
        }
        var a = this.cfg.steps[this.getStepIndex(this.currentStep) + 1];
        this.loadStep(a, false)
    }
```

My understanding is like that: The wizard first execute the custom handler and if the custom handler returns false it should not load the next tab (call PrimeFaces.widget.Wizard.loadStep). But actually what happens is that the custom handler is called **then** called PrimeFaces.widget.Wizard.loadStep function of the wizard and so the next tab is focused.

Is my understanding wrong, or this is a bug in PF?

Comment: PF version? Otherwise I might be chasing ghosts trying to replicate

Comment: I'm using Primefaces 5.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just did a little checking, The 'order' is ok, so the **then** as you state it is not wrong, the problem is that it is called **anyway**, even if you (think) you return false.

The problem is this:

```
this.cfg.onnext.call(this);
```

It **always** returns `undefined`. It fails in 5.3 to and in 5.1 and 5.0 and 4.0, so this initially lead me to think it either was never fully tested or something changed in recent browsers. But what actually happens is that the function one defines (demo in my case) is wrapped in an anonymous function

```
function (){demo()}
```

without a return value, so not

```
function (){return demo()}
```

Having no 'return', results in it never returning the actual value you return from your function but always 'undefined'.

This lead me to think to in the `onnext="demo()"` just add the return... so make it `onnext="return demo()"` et voila, it works.

Keep in mind that this is easy to debug with a javascript debugger and you can always override functions to add additional log statements.

Code I tested with:

```
<html  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
       xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
       xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
<h:head />
<h:body>
<h:form id="form">

    <p:wizard onnext="demo()" flowListener="#{mailTemplateBean.onFlowProcess}">
        <p:tab title="Step 1"/>
        <p:tab title="Step 2"/>
        <p:tab title="Step 3"/>
        <p:tab title="Step 4"/>

    </p:wizard>

    <script>

    PrimeFaces.widget.Wizard.prototype.next = function() {
        if(this.cfg.onnext) {
            var value = this.cfg.onnext.call(this);
            console.log("Return: " + value + " function: " + this.cfg.onnext);
            if(value === false) {
                return;
            }
        }

        var targetStepIndex = this.getStepIndex(this.currentStep) + 1;
        if(targetStepIndex &lt; this.cfg.steps.length) {
            var stepToGo = this.cfg.steps[targetStepIndex];
            this.loadStep(stepToGo, false);
        }
    }

    function demo() {
        var bla = confirm("Sure?");
        console.log("Choosen: " + bla);
        return bla;
    }</script>

</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

And please file an issue with PF and ask them to either add this to the docs, or have them fix the 'wrapping' of the function in it adding an automagic return.

Comment: Thanks Kukeltje, that was informative and very helpful. Your work around was very helpful too. I'll report that to PF issue tracker.